# Report not showing all data and not paginating

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I've returned to our reports collection after a couple of years away, and added a new report which has a simple tablix containing a few columns, but many rows from the dataset.

The problem is, the report (in Preview in VS, and when run on the Report Server) only shows *some* of the rows returned by the dataset, and doesn't enable the page navigation icons in order to scroll through the data to access the rest.

Where do I find the settings which control these things, please?

UPDATE:
Looking at some pre-existing reports, it seem that these exhibit the same problem -  it would appear that SSRS can only display about 5,000 rows regardless of how many the dataset contains.

Comment: First, your new report does it return rows enough to have pagination. Second somewhere in your Source of dataset a. Limit is set which is returning only 5k records.  Link for reference https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108869/how-to-get-past-the-5000-row-limit-in-a-sql-server-reporting-services-tablix-rep

Comment: Problem found (and resolved). There is a 'hidden' setting in the XML code (not available via the UI AFAIK) called InteractiveHeight. Removing this line resulted in the paging starting to work.

Comment: Perfect makes sense. Cool

Answer (score 1):

There is a 'hidden' setting in the XML code (not available via the UI AFAIK) called InteractiveHeight. Removing this line resulted in the paging starting to work